# Writing report viewer content to an existing excel file in a new sheet

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I want to export the report viewer contents into an excel sheet. Below code is writing successfully but creates a new excel file. However I want to open an existing excel sheet and place the report viewer content into new worksheet.

```
byte[] bytes = viewer.LocalReport.Render("Excel", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);
System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(@"d:\output.xls", System.IO.FileMode.Create);
fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
fs.close();
```

Comment: Without the code for the `viewer.LocalReport.Render()` method it'll be hard to help you. What is that method doing, and how is it doing it? Is it using some kind of 3rd part library like OpenXML, or is it creating a HTML response?

Comment: viewer is Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer object where I am loading a rdlc report and setting the data sources in rdlc report. `Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer viewer = new ReportViewer();
            viewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
viewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Report/R3PnLProject.rdlc");
viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(resIncme);`